# Emacs inline comment columns: what on earth is going on?

Tags: emacs, comments

I'm currently working in Python, but I don't think this is specifically a Python issue – I've been confused by this in, e.g., Java as well. I'm using Aquamacs on a Mac, but that shouldn't matter either.

I'm getting tired of the craziness in placement of inline comments. I've tried reading the relevant documentation, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me decipher what is going on?

Below is an example, where I started an experiment with all the inline comments aligned (manually), with the `#` in column 39. Then, for each of the lines containing an inline comment from top to bottom, I placed the cursor on that line and did `comment-indent`. The result was what you see below. The first two comments were placed in column 42, the next two in column 49, and the final three stayed where they were in column 39.

The value of `comment-column` is 48 in the buffer.

```
def fgparam_for_m(m):
    h = (m-1).bit_length()                # height of natural bunch
    s = (1 << h) - m                      # short cws in natural bunch
    return Mparams(m, h, s)

def fgparam_for_mn(m, n):
    m = m + n%m                                  # size of tail bunch
    dt = (n-m)//m                                # depth of tail bunch
    if 2*m < 3*m:
        h = (m-1).bit_length() + 1     # height of tail bunch
        s = (1 << h-1) - m             # short cws in tail bunch
        dn = 1                         # depth of leaf n in tail bunch
    else:
        h = (m + m//3 - 1).bit_length()
        s = 3*(1 << h-2) - m
        dn = 2
    return Nparams(m, h, s, dt, m*dt, dn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the *right* hand side and you'll see that all 3 blocks have the furthest character ("h") in the same column.  That's because `comment-indent` also tries not to go past `fill-column` (which is apparently set to 70 for you).

I must admit that I don't know why you got the middle block in column 49 rather than 48, tho.

Comment: Thanks, I can't see anything about that in the doc. Increasing fill-column changed the behavior: it sends the common way off to the right. Still unpredictable to me. Is it trying to line up comments as close to fill-column as possible? Any idea what I could do to simply line up the LEFT side of the comments, preferably on column 48? (Or 49, no big deal.) I tried reading the Lisp source, but it's a mess, probably easier to write my own from scratch than figuring that out. Currently, I have to manually place the one in the first line in each block of adjacent comments.

Comment: If it goes further than `comment-column`, then there's probably a bug somewhere.  Can you reproduce the problem in `emacs -Q`?  If so, I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.